# YML with multiple files: Unhandled rejection YAMLException: duplicated mapping key

Tags: yaml, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I tried to separate my resources field in multiple files in project. Most of then worked fine, but only this file, where I declare CognitoUserPool + CognitoUserPoolClient trowed this exception:

```
Unhandled rejection YAMLException: duplicated mapping key in "/home/uriel/Desktop/Foo/Backend/MultipleFile/backend-foo/resources/cognitoUserPoolFoo.yml" at line 20, column 3:
            Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient 
      ^
    at generateError (/home/uriel/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:167:10)
```

I've already checked logical and indentation problems. This same lines worked on single file, they only throw this error when I move them to another YML file and import it.

Main YML file importing the another one

```
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-offline

resources:  

  - ${file(resources/cognitoUserPoolFoo.yml)}
```

File imported, the one that throw error.

```
Resources:
    CognitoUserPoolFoo:
        Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
        Properties:
            MfaConfiguration: OFF
            UserPoolName: foo-${self:provider.stage}
            EmailConfiguration:
                ReplyToEmailAddress: foo@test.com
                SourceArn: "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:123456789012:identity/foo@test.com"
            AutoVerifiedAttributes:
                - email
            Policies:
                PasswordPolicy:
                    MinimumLength: 6
                    RequireLowercase: True
                    RequireNumbers: True
                    RequireSymbols: False
                    RequireUppercase: True
    FooCognitoUserPoolClient: 
        Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient 
        Properties: 
            ClientName: FooWebApp-${self:provider.stage}
            GenerateSecret: false 
            UserPoolId: 
                Ref: "CognitoUserPoolFoo"
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/), `resources` does not take a sequence as child, but directly the mapping that is the root of the other file. So your include should rather be `resources: ${file(resources/cognitoUserPoolFoo.yml)}`; however I don't know if that has anything to do with the error.

Comment: The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is XML based and looks completely different from the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) format, which is what you have. The [recommended file extension](http://yaml.org/faq.html) for *YAML* files has been  `.yaml` since 2006.

Comment: @flyx Thank you for comment. I used this notation based on this repository: https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-stack-demo-api

Comment: @urielbra only the part starting with `$` is special notation; the preceding `-` is standard YAML, meaning the start of a sequence item. Since the structure doesn't expect a sequence there, you should definitely drop it.